# how to store a array values into session variable in php

Tags: php

i want to store the value of array into session variable and want to use that  session variable in another page for printing all the subject name but while going to print i am getting blank page.

```
<?php
session_start();
$colname=array();
$i=0;
while($i<10)
{
$colname[$i]=$i;
$i++;
}
echo"$colname[0]";
echo"$colname[1]";
echo"$colname[2]";
echo"$colname[3]";
echo"$colname[4]";
echo"$colname[5]";
echo"$colname[6]";
echo"$colname[7]";
echo"$colname[8]";
echo"$colname[9]";
$_SESSION['sub1']=$colname[0];
$_SESSION['sub2']=$colname[1];
$_SESSION['sub3']=$colname[2];
$_SESSION['sub4']=$colname[3];
$_SESSION['sub5']=$colname[4];
$_SESSION['sub6']=$colname[5];
$_SESSION['sub7']=$colname[6];
$_SESSION['sub8']=$colname[7];
$_SESSION['sub9']=$colname[8];
$_SESSION['sub10']=$colname[9];
?>
```

while using the above session variable into another page nothing get displayed

Comment: `session_start()` ? Can't you just do something like `$_SESSION['colname'] = $colname;`

Comment: how do you print your array ?

Comment: You can assign an array to a session variable, so you could just do: `$_SESSION['my_array'] = $colname;`. And you need to post the code of the second page.

Comment: Did you start your session (`session_start()`) on the another page before you print the session variable?

Comment: if i assign an entire array to session variable how can i print that array values in the next page.i dont know how to do that.can you tel me. thanks mr.jeroen